# Tkinter Text Widget storing text

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to simply create a text box where the user can type in multiple lines of text and save it as a text file. Unfortunately, my error is "Nonetype, object has no attribute 'get' in the 4th line of the below code snippet. I have tried using the Entry widget instead and it worked fine with the identical lines. However, one line was simply not enough. What am I missing? Thank you.

```
def save():
file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')
if file != None:
    data = entryBox.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
    file.write(data)
    file.close()

fr = Frame(root,height=100, width=100)
fr.pack()

entryLabel = Label (fr, text = "Forecast Notes:").pack(side = TOP)

entryBox = Text (fr, width = 50, height=20).pack()

saveButton = Button (fr, text = "Save", command = save).pack()
clearButton = Button (fr, text = "Clear", command = clear).pack(side=TOP)
```

Comment: Did you do _any_ searching of this website for this error? This type of question has been asked and answered many times. If you did a search but never got a good result, perhaps you can share with us what you searched for so maybe we can make the answers easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pack()` has no return value.
You have to assign create the object, assign it to the variable and pack it after that.

For example, change this:

```
entryBox = Text (fr, width = 50, height=20).pack()
```

into this:

```
entryBox = Text (fr, width = 50, height=20)
entryBox.pack()
```